# terraform if local.environment does not equal "123" do this, else do nothing

Tags: azure, if-statement, terraform

I am trying to get some IP restrictions on all my azure webapps except 1, I am using terraform to code the environments but cannot figure out how to code the following statement "if local.environment does not equal "123" do this, else do nothing"

any suggestions?  I have been searching for sometime now and can't find an example of something like I am trying to do.

Thanks in advance

things I have tried that have not worked:

all of the below lines I have tried in this block:

```
resource "azurerm_windows_web_app" "myApp" {

#stuff here

site_config {

#stuff here

ip_restriction { 
        
        name       = "Testname"
        ip_address = "8.8.8.8/32"
        action     = "Allow"
        priority   = "796"
      }
}
}

count = local.environment == "123" ? 1 : 0

for_each = local.environment ? [] : ["123"]

for_each = local.environment ? [] : ["1"]

value = [for x in local.environment: x.id if x.id == "123"]
```

Comment: Can you post a resource to which this is being applied. You can't use count against a var or local, it would have to be placed in the resource you are binding to in order to work the way you posted.

Comment: resource added!

Answer (score 0):

> terraform if local.environment does not equal "123" do this, else do nothing:

*To achieve this, I modified your code as below and it worked for me as expected.*

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
variable "environment"{}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "resourcegroup"
  location = "xxxxx"
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "example"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  sku_name            = "P1v2"
  os_type             = "Windows"
}

resource "azurerm_windows_web_app" "myApp" {
  count              = var.environment != "123" ? 1 : 0
  name                = "example"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_service_plan.example.location
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.example.id

  site_config {
    
      ip_restriction { 
      name       = "Testname"
      ip_address = "8.8.8.8/32"
      action     = "Allow"
      priority   = "796"
    }

}
}
```

*Successfully validated the configuration:*

[image]

`terraform plan`:

[image]

[image]

Refer [terraform registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/windows_web_app) template for the web app deployment.

Comment: Thank you for this!!  my question now would be, can I put the count      = var.environment != "123" ? 1 : 0, into the ip restrictions block?  that is the main goal of what I am trying to do, I need the "123" environment to not have the IP restrictions, but I have 3 other environments that are exactly the same that do need to have the IP restrictions on them.

Thank you again for your help!

Comment: You can use `foreach` loop to check 123 inside the Ip restrictions block. @Jimbo311